# remote php-fpm is getting errors

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fpm

I am trying to run a wordpress in docker with separate container on nginx and php-fpm; I have configured the nginx to reach the php-fpm container for the php. I can see that the nginx is forwarding the php file to the fpm container but that will fail. I can see the following error on the container:

```
web_1  | 2018/06/07 06:12:57 [error] 7#7: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: wp.startech-rd.tk, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.3:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Edit: Adding docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - php
    image: nginx:latest
    hostname: wp.startech-rd.tk
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db:3306
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/wp.startech-rd.tk.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./wp:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw

  db:
    image: percona:5.7
    hostname: db.startech-rd.tk
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp_password

  php:
    image: busterm/php7.2-fpm
    hostname: php.startech-rd.tk
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 9000
```

Any idea how can get this fixed?

Comment: Can you provide your docker-compose.yml? Could be hard to determine the error only based on the log output.

Comment: docker-compose.yml was added to the description